# pandas concatenate part of index in row attending condition

Tags: pandas, append, filtering

I have a table listing in rows invoices and in rows kind of reparation and also power of the engine

The power of the engine contains always the symbol '/'

so filtering the index I have:

[image]

What I desire is a new row containing for every invoice a list of the different powers

For instance for 'inv123' the new row should contain ['400/HP','500kw/h']

So far I have the following code:
from itertools import compress

```
 boolean_filter = DF.index.str.contains('/') & DF['inv123']
 indexlist =list(DF.index)
 mylist = list(compress(indexlist, boolean_filter))
 # you can generate it in one liner
 mylist = list(compress(DF.index,DF.index.str.contains('/') & DF['inv123']))

print(mylist)
```

Result

```
['400/HP', '500/kwh']
```

This is the value I have to add in row='concatenate" column='inv123'

I encounter a number of problems

- a) I am not able to that in a pythonic way (no loops)
- b) when adding an empty row with:

  DF.append(pd.Series(name='concatenate'))

the dtype of the 0s,1s (integers) changes to float, which makes the code not reusable (not being boolean anymore)

Some idea how to approach the problem?

But still I would have to loop over every column

Comment: `DF.where(DF==1).stack()` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution

```
from itertools import compress
lc=[list(compress(DF.index,DF.index.str.contains('/') & DF.iloc[:,i])) for i in range(len(DF.columns))]
```

the first thing there is compress a the list of the index with the boolean of every column (DF.iloc[:,i])

As a result I obtain a list in wich every element is a list of the wanted values.

The solution is not at all elegant.
It took me a few hours.